# Add languages to Handsontable react

Tags: reactjs, handsontable

I'm using Handsontable react, and when I want to set language on column I've got error: 'Unknown culture : de-DE'. In numbro there is file languages.min.js that should be imported, but after I've added 'import 'numbro/dist/languages.js' in file with react-handsontable it doesn't change anything. How should I append languages to react-handsontable?

Answer (score 0):

There is an limitation within Numbro v1 itself where languages loaded globally are not available for Numbro instance used by Handsontable internally. The proposed solution (update to Numbro v2) already awaits for code review [PR #5127](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/pull/5127). If everything goes well this PR will land in the upcoming version of Handsontable.

**Edit:**
Released in Handsontable 4.0.0.